# Do I have to sync gradle project in Android studio everytime I start a new project?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

Everytime whenever I start a new project it shows the gradle sync is failed[![enter image description here][1]][1]....is this necessary to sync the gradle every time whenever i start a new project

Comment: Please be clear with your codes which you have used in your program.

Comment: Whenever I start a new project in android studio 3.1 ...it shows a message that gradle sync is failed buy I already sync gradle in my previous project  ..is this necessary to sync gradle everytime whenever I start a new project

Answer (score 0):

What is synced here is the project configuration expressed in the *.gradle files with the project configuration native in Android Studio. So, yes, this is necessary for each project. It is also necessary after you made changes to any of the *.gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Whenever you open a project in android studio,it will sync the gradle files everytime,And when you edit or implement any new library in .gradle file,that time also gradle build sync.

In your project gradle build is keep failing,this happens when your code have some error or its possible that error is in .gradle file.

Comment: Do I need to have internet connection everytime whenever I want to create a new project in android studio  ?

Comment: No its not necessary.Internet connection is only needed when you want to add some new library.